# Database Administrator

Tags: ldap, novell, edirectory

I have a Novell LDAP server running on RHEL. and I want to authenticate my LDAP users from the Website on one of my machine having HTTP, so I use in the httpd.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Stooges Web Site: Login with user id"
   AuthBasicProvider ldap
   AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
   AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://ldap1.server.com:636/o=ae-name?cn"
   AuthLDAPBindDN "cn=psg_admin,o=ae-name"
   AuthLDAPBindPassword ldappass
   require valid-user

</Directory>
```

the error I recieve is ......

```
[31231] auth_ldap authenticate: user ldap-user1 authentication failed; URI / [LDAP: ldap_simple_bind_s() failed][Invalid credentials]
[Thu Feb 02 08:04:39 2012] [error] [client 10.231.101.113] user ldap-user1: authentication failure for "/": Password Mismatch
```

Is there anything missing or am I making any mistake please guide me in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not passing in a user name to authenticate with. From the "authentication failure for "/"" bit.

What are you seeing in DStrace on the eDirectory server, with the LDAP trace tag enabled?

Go to the server:8008 and you should be prompted to login (or it might be on 8028, depends on what eDirectory is running on.  Or 8010).

If you authenticate, change the url to /nds/trace and you there is a configure button.  Clear All, select LDAP, switch to Trace Live (lightning bolt icon) and see what happens on the server end when you try to connect.